# lxml python - Extracting a tag and iterating over the children

Tags: python, lxml

I am using lxml to get a tag as follows:

```
el = doc.get_element_by_id('productDescription')
```

From my understanding `el` just contains that tag and its children.

When I use `el.iterdescendants()` I get tags outside of the main tag that I am extracting!
How is this possible? (This is amazon.com so the DOM is good).

```
 el = doc.get_element_by_id('productDescription')
 for j in el.iterdescendants():
     print j.tag
```

What is the proper way to extract a tag and only work with the descendants?

Comment: Do you happen to have a snippet of the XML?

Comment: Is the result any different if you use CSSSelector (from lxml.cssselect import CSSSelector)?

Comment: It would be nice if you would show some input and the output. Everything looks correct (if only you do want to iterate descendants and not children)

Answer (score 0):

You should use CSSSelector

```
import CSSSelector
```

because this is much more reliable !!!